# Button with image wont lie under centered text

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to get a button with a background in it, which I finally achieved, but now I have come into another problem, and I just can't seem to get any solution to it, since the text is in the right spot, but the button with the image in it is offset above it. All I want to do with this is place the button and image under the text.

```css
html {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}

body {
  background-image: url(screenshots/main.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 110%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06);
  color: #545454;
  font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 1.5;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 100;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  color: #222;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 1.3;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-top 100px;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 1.3em;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #0083e8;
}

b,
strong {
  font-weight: 600;
}

samp {
  display: none;
}

img {
  animation: colorize 2s cubic-bezier(0, 0, .78, .36) 1;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  height=125px width=222px white-space: nowrap;
}

.buttons a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 60px 20px 0;
  height: 125px;
  width: 222px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: rgb(216, 216, 216) rgb(209, 209, 209) rgb(186, 186, 186);
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000;
  line-height: 125px;
  text-align: center;
}

.dust2 {}

@keyframes colorize {
  0% {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(0%);
    filter: grayscale(0%);
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>CS:GO Interactive Tools</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Raisaga's interactive CS:GO map and tools.">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Rai's CS:GO <br /> Interactive Tool</h1>

  <div class="buttons">
    <a href="dust2.html"><img src="screenshots/MapBGs/Dust2.jpg">DUST 2</a>
    <a href="mirage.html">MIRAGE</a>
    <a href="cache.html">CACHE</a>
    <a href="overpass.html">OVERPASS</a>
    <a href="inferno.html">INFERNO</a>
    <a href="train.html">TRAIN</a>
    <a href="cobblestone.html">COBBLESTONE</a>
    <a href="office.html">OFFICE</a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use background image instead

Comment: can you add an image from placeholder.com or lorempixel to your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to achieve something like this?

All i did was change your styling of your buttons

```
.buttons a{
  display: inline-block;
  height: 125px;
  width: 222px;
  border-radius: 7px;
  border: 4px solid;
  border-color: rgb(216, 216, 216) rgb(209, 209, 209) rgb(186, 186, 186);
  text-align: center;
  margin: 60px 20px 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.buttons a img{
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

I also switched the image and the text inside the html

```
<a href="dust2.html">
  <span class="heading">DUST 2</span>
  <img src="screenshots/MapBGs/Dust2.jpg" />
</a>
```

Take a look at the plunkr and let me know if this is correct

[Look at plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NicVSBzWxVeGqmzHdn2i?p=preview)

--UPDATE--

One way you could do it is to give each button a background image instead of an inline image

OR

You could absolute position your text.  like so:

CSS

```
.heading{
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 100;
  top: 50px;
  left: 85px;
}
```

HTML

```
<a href="dust2.html">
  <span class="heading">DUST 2</span>
  <img src="screenshots/MapBGs/Dust2.jpg">
</a>
```

[Updated plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/NicVSBzWxVeGqmzHdn2i?p=preview)

Comment: Sort of, I am trying to get the image to fill the whole button, and have the text centered inside of it, rather than lie above it.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for! Thanks a lot for the help, I really appreciate it.

Comment: Cool, no problem.